# How to generate effectively a random number that only contains unique digits in Python?

Tags: python, list, random

```
import random

def get_number(size):
  result = [random.randint(1,9)]
  digits = list(range(0,10))
  digits.remove(result[0])
  if(size > 1):
    result += random.sample(digits,size-1)
  return ''.join(map(str,result))

print(get_number(4))
```

I solved the problem, but I feel that it's clumsy. 
How can I do this more effectively and more elegant?

Comment: Take all digits (`string.digits`), shuffle them randomly (`random.shuffle`), slice to required length (`...[:size]`).

Comment: Strictly, shuffling the whole list is more work than necessary.  You don't need to shuffle digits you're not going to return.  Is there a variant of `shuffle` which produces a random subset of a given size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuffle is the way to go as suggested by @jonrsharpe:

```
import random

def get_number(size):
    l = [ str(i) for i in list(range(10))]
    while l[0] == '0':
        random.shuffle(l)
    return int("".join(l[:size]))
```

Limits:

- is you ask for a number of more than 10 digits, you will only get 10 digits
- it can take some steps if first digit is initially a 0

Answer (score 0):

Just use shuffle:

```
import string

x = list(string.digits)
random.shuffle(x)

print int(str(random.choice(range(1, 10))) + "".join(x[:3]))
```

Comment: These numbers (because of the generation method of the first digit) are not necessary contains only unique numbers. But the idea is good, you just have to remove that first digit from x before concatenating the tail of the number.